# Micronaut inject yml properties in java

Tags: java, micronaut, inject

I'm using micronaut and I have a list of properties defined in the application yml file, this is an example:

```
inbound:
  validations:
    VALIDATION1:
      description: bla bla
      filter:
        erps:
          - erp1
        type:
          - type1
    VALIDATION2:
      description: bla bla
      filter:
        erps:
          - erp1
        type:
          - type1
    VALIDATION3:
      description: bla bla
      filter:
        erps:
          - erp1
        type:
          - type1
```

I want to inject each of this items in a java class, I have defined this one:

```
@Data
@EachProperty("inbound.validations")
public class ConfigBusinessProductValidator {
    public ConfigBusinessProductValidator(@Parameter BusinessValidator.VALIDATION_ID validationId) {
        this.validationId = validationId;
    }
    
    private BusinessValidator.VALIDATION_ID validationId;

    private String description;

    private FilterConfig filter;
    
    public class FilterConfig{
        private Set<ErpEnum> erps;
        private Set<LogisticsTypeEnum> logisticsType;
        private Set<CompanyEnum> ownerCompany;
    }

}
```

This is working for the fields that are in the root but not for the filter.

How can I define the class so micronaut can inject the attributes under filter level?

Comment: Take a look at this guide: https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-configuration.html